# Graph of second order polynomials

Tags: plotting, manipulate, polynomials

As I mentioned before, I want to write a notebook for teaching graphs of second order polynomials that shows discriminant and the conditions when a>0, a<0, having real roots, having no real roots. I got this but it is not what I want to see after evaluating apparently:(
How can I fix it?

```
s = Manipulate[
  Plot[a x^2 + b x + c, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-50, 50}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Row[{a x^2 + b x + c == y, ";discriminant=", 
      b^2 - 4 a c}]], {{a, .1}, -10, 10, 
   Appearance -> "Open"}, {{b, .1}, -10, 10, 
   Appearance -> "Open"}, {{c, .1}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Open"}];
if[b^2 - 4 a c > 0, 
 Return["there are two different real roots", s]]; if[
 b^2 - 4 a c < 0, Return["there are no real roots", s]];
if[b^2 - 4 a c == 0, Return["there are two real same roots", s]]
```

Comment: To start with, `if` should be `If`, and `Return` needs to be inside some sort of enclosing construct such as a function (but should not be used in this context anyway). It would be better to use `Which` inside the `Manipulate` to decide on a particular form of annotation to display next to the plot. By the way, "two same roots" are usually known as *a (doubly) degenerate root* in English.

Comment: This is your 3rd question on the site. I think it's about time that you learn to format your code properly. See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). Expecting others to do this for you shows little respect for their time.

Comment: "As I mentioned before" Where?

Comment: @Pickett I think OP means in [this identical question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95074/27951) he/she posted shorly before the present one.

Comment: @MarcoB I don't really care, just making a point. But thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 8):

Here is a quick `Manipulate` to get you started.

```
Manipulate[
   Module[{d = b^2 - 4 a c, r},
      If[d >= 0, 
         r = {{(-b - Sqrt[d])/(2 a), 0}, {(-b + Sqrt[d])/(2 a), 0}}, 
         r = {{-1000, 0}, {1000, 0}}];
      Plot[a x^2 + b x + c, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-50, 50},
           PlotLabel -> Row[{
              a x^2 + b x + c == y,
              "\n discriminant=", b^2 - 4 a c,
              Which[
                 d < 0, "\n No Roots",
                 d == 0, "\n Duplicate Root",
                 d > 0, "\n Two Roots"]}],
           Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.015], Point[r]}]],
      {{a, .1}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
      {{b, .1}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
      {{c, .1}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: roots of quadratic equation]